# How to tell "dnf search" to list only matches in the package name (or name and summary), but not only in the summary?

Tags: package-management, output, dnf

On RHEL/CentOS the package manager `dnf` can search for strings in the names and summaries of packages. How can I tell it to list only matches in the name (or in name *and* summary), but not in the summary only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DNF unfortunately doesn't have an option to search only in the package name, there is an [old RFE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=963140) for this feature, but there was no activity since 2015.

You can try using `dnf list` which can show both installed and available packages and supports [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expressions so it can be potentially used for searching by name only

```
$ sudo dnf list "*anaconda*"
anaconda.x86_64
anaconda-core.x86_64
anaconda-dracut.x86_64
anaconda-gui.x86_64
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Supercool that you point out a way with another dnf command!